# Bootstrap v2.3 collapse and data-parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

i'm using Php 5.3 symfony 2 and Bootstrap v2.3

i wanna do an accordion like this (Bootstrap 3) :

http://jsfiddle.net/jvx7oven/

But i'm using Bootstrap v2.3 and the `#data-parent` attribute doesnt work..

i wanna do a 3 level accordion and all elements closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.

**Note:** The data-parent attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.

Please help me , i did it with Bootstrap2 in this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/umjmb33n/

But the third level "MONTH" doesnt closed when one is shown..

Comment: Why not update to bootstrap 3.3.7 or 4 alpha-6?

Comment: I dont know how to do, i'm scared to destroy all my project..

Comment: You won't destroy anything by updating bootstrap.The way of updating bootstrap depends on how you've included bootstrap in your project. Did you paste the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js files in your project or did you use the CDN ?. In the newer bootstrap versions it's very simple to create these kind of tab / menu structured templates.

Comment: It was a bad data-parent link .. remember to link your data-parent attribute to the accordion-group who wrap the entire bloc :)